# Java / Refactoring switch case

Tags: java, refactoring

I am trying to refactor the next case:

```
  class Gen{
    public void startClick(A a, B b, List<C> lstC, SortX sort){
     for (int i=0; i<lstC.size(); i++){
        try{
        // some code with try and catch statement
         switch (sort){
        case SortA:
              newOne(a, b, lstc);
              break;
        case SortB: 
              otherfunction(a);
              break;
        case SortC:
              someotherfunction(lstC, a);
              break;
          }
       }
      } catch (Exception e){ //some code}
     } 
}
```

I try to create to and case an object, like we see here: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

So I create an object: `SortOfType`, and then for each case I create also an object (`SortA`, `SortB`, `SortC`). The function in `SortOfType` get the instance of `Gen`, and so the other Sort objects. What I don't success is to call the sortOfType fron the class Gen. How can I do it? this refactoring is possible here?

Comment: There's no such thing as an `exception`, and there is no `lstc` variable there. However, there is an `Exception` and `lstC` variable. And I'm not sure what a `clase` is...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do here.  Can you clear that up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You define an interface which is called when an action is required

```
public interface SortX {
    public void startClick(A a, B b, C c);
}

public enum SortAEnum implements SortX<A, B, C> {
    SortA {
         public void startClick(A a, B b, C c) {
              newOne(a, b, c);
         }
    }, SortB {
         public void startClick(A a, B b, C c) {
              otherfunction(a);
         }
    }, SortB {
         public void startClick(A a, B b, C c) {
              someotherfunction(c, a);
         }
    }
}

public static void startClick(A a, B b, List<C extends OnClick> lstC, SortX sort){
   for (int i=0; i<lstC.size(); i++){
      sort.startClick(a, b, lstC.get(i));
   }
}
```

Comment: I originally edited your code to correct what I thought was a minor error, now I think I need to leave you to do that. Did you mean to have `SortAEnum implements SortX<A, B, C>` or did you just mean `SortAEnum implements SortX`? Also, you have two `SortB` values in your enum.

Comment: but is the A,B,C object is not in the same project of SortAEnum,the implements is not complemented