# Java refactoring interlinked switch/if statement with polymorphism

Tags: java, switch-statement, polymorphism, refactoring

I am aware of how to replace a switch statement through polymorphism, like it is explained for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953054/java-refactoring-switch-case).

In my case however I have two Enum:

```
public enum EleType {
    INTEGER, 
    CHARACTER
}
```

and

```
public enum SorterType {
    BUBBLE,
    INSERTION
}
```

and the switch/if I would like to refactor has the structure:

```
if ( eleType == EleType.INTEGER ) {
    switch ( sorterType ) {
        case BUBBLE:
             composition = new SorterComposition<Integer>(new BubbleSort<Integer>(), randomList);
             break;
        case INSERTION:
             composition = new SorterComposition<Integer>(new InsertionSort<Integer>(), randomList);
             break;
    }
} else if ( eleType == EleType.CHARACTER ) {
    switch ( sorterType ) {
        case BUBBLE:
             composition = new SorterComposition<Character>(new BubbleSort<Character>(), randomList);
             break;
        case INSERTION:
             composition = new SorterComposition<Character>(new InsertionSort<Character>(), randomList);
             break;
    }
}
```

Because both enum appear together and both affect the SorterComposition part, I am unsure how to refactor this structure. Also I am unsure how to get the "Integer"/"Character" generic types from EleType.INTEGER or EleType.CHARACTER respectively without using conditional statements.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you implement the code like this?

```
public static <T> SorterComposition<T> createComposition(SorterType type, <Type of randomList>) {
    switch (type) {
        case BUBBLE:
            return new SorterComposition<T>(new BubbleSort<T>(), randomList);
        case INSERTION:
            return new SorterComposition<T>(new InsertionSort<T>(), randomList);
        default:
            throw <Exception>
    }
}
```

---

Or, you can change the `EleType` class a little bit.

```
public enum EleType {
    INTEGER(Integer.class), CHARACTER(Character.class);
    private EleType(Class cl) { this.classType = cl; }
    public Class getClassType() { return classType; }
    private final Class classType;
}
```

and use this code instead of the `createComposition` above.

```
public static <T> SorterComposition<T> createComposition(Class<T> eleType, SorterType type, <Type of randomList>) {
    switch (type) {
        case BUBBLE:
            return new SorterComposition<T>(new BubbleSort<T>(), randomList);
        case INSERTION:
            return new SorterComposition<T>(new InsertionSort<T>(), randomList);
        default:
            throw <Exception>
    }
}
```

and when you use it, use `composition = createComposition(eleType.getClassType(), sorterType, randomList);`

---

To avoid `switch` of `SorterType` in a gentle way, maybe you can use in add a `Supplier` field into `SorterType`.

```
public enum SorterType {
    BUBBLE(() -> new BubbleSort()),
    INSERTION(() -> new InsertionSort());

    private SorterType(Supplier<Sort> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public Sort getSort() {
        return supplier.get();
    }

    private final Supplier<Sort> supplier;
}
```

Comment: Changing the EleType seems to solve my second problem (mapping from EleType to Integer.class, etc). However I still want to get rid of the switch statement somehow.

Comment: How about the code in the update? Add a field to `EleType`, and when calling `createComposition`, pass in `eleType.getClassType()`.

Comment: How does this get rid of the switch of `SorterType` ?

Comment: I would avoid the Supplier approach, as it creates raw types (meaning, `new BubbleSort` instead of `new BubbleSort<Integer>`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use double dispatch. I have provided a skeleton implementation below.
However some consider [double dispatch a code smell.](https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2010/04/19/double-dispatch-is-a-code-smell/) In this instance your EleType seems suspect to me. All you are doing with it in this example is use it for your generic type declaration.

```
    public enum EleType {
    INTEGER {
        SorterComposition getSorter(SorterType s) {
            return s.getIntegerSorter();
        }
    }, 
    CHARACTER{
        SorterComposition getSorter(SorterType s) {
            return s.getChracterSorter();
        }

    };

    abstract SorterComposition getSorter(SorterType s);
};

public enum SorterType {
    BUBBLE {
        SorterComposition getIntegerSorter() {return new BubbleSort<Integer>();}
        SorterComposition getChracterSorter() {return new BubbleSort<Character>();}
    },
    INSERTION{
        SorterComposition getIntegerSorter() {return new InsertionSort<Integer>();}
        SorterComposition getChracterSorter() {return new InsertionSort<Character>();}
    };

    abstract SorterComposition getIntegerSorter();
    abstract SorterComposition getChracterSorter();

};
```